# Error while enabling USB debugging on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, developer-tools, usb-debugging

I am trying to enable USB debugging for my project as per [the official android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up?utm_source=udacity&utm_medium=mooc&utm_term=android&utm_content=dev_mode&utm_campaign=training). However, when I wrote this in my build.gradle file:

```
android {
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
```

I get an error saying:

> Error:(25, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'Check' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Gradle settings
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin

When I try to enable USB debugging from the AndiodManifest file (without modifying the build.gradle file):

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

I get an error saying:

> Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   It's best to leave out the android:debuggable attribute from the manifest. If you do, then the tools will automatically insert android:debuggable=true when building an APK to debug on an emulator or device. And when you perform a release build, such as Exporting APK, it will automatically set it to false.  If on the other hand you specify a specific value in the manifest file, then the tools will always use it. This can lead to accidentally publishing your app with debug information.

I have tried both methods mentioned in the documentation. How do I enable USB debugging?

EDIT (this is the build.gradle file):

```
/* Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.*/

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    } 
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled USB Debugging on your device?

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: @Alok Gupta yes, I have. But I do not even reach debugging on my device. I get errors in the file itself.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have added it as an edit in the question.